# use SED recursively in linux?

Tags: linux, unix, shell, sed

I want to implement the following command recursively

```
sed -i 's/href=\"1\//href=\"\/1\//g' ./*
```

so that it replaces all href="1 with href="/1 in all sub-directories.   Is there a flag I can add to this command to achieve the results I want?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/href=\"1\//href=\"\/1\//g'
```

Comment: It should be -0 - it matches up with -print0 in the find - edited the post.

Comment: I find that `find . -type f | xargs sed -i 's/href=\"1\//href=\"\/1\//g'` can produce the same results.  Will there be pitfalls to this approach?

Answer (score 2):

Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/5130044/833771, if the target directory is a Git or SVN root, you should use:

`find . -not \( -name .svn -prune -o -name .git -prune \) -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/href=\"1\//href=\"\/1\//g'`