# Dropping the -print0 and -0 flags from find and xargs

Tags: bash, find, xargs

Almost 10 years ago, I asked this question

[use SED recursively in linux?](https://serverfault.com/questions/172806/use-sed-recursively-in-linux)

and got this useful command `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/regex_search_term/replace_term/g'`

I decided to learn more about the `find`, `xargs` and `sed` statement. On Ubuntu 18.04 in bash version 4.4.20(1)-release, I can simplify the statement to this:

`find . -type f -print | xargs sed -i 's/regex_search_term/replace_term/g'`

Which can then be simplified again to this:

`find . -type f | xargs sed -i 's/regex_search_term/replace_term/g'`

So my question is, are there any drawbacks to not using the `-print0` flag with the  `-0` flag of `find` and `xargs` respectively?  And are there any drawbacks to dropping the `-print` flag altogether?  Are they explicitly used for compatibility with different unix like systems?

Comment: What happens with a file having spaces in its name? or newlines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The versions that don't use `-print0` and `xargs -0` will get confused by a number of rare-but-legal characters in filenames, including spaces, tabs, newlines, quotes, and backslashes. A zero byte (the ASCII NUL character) is the only thing that *cannot* occur in a file path, so using it as a delimiter avoids these potential problems.

But there's actually a simpler way. Modern versions of `find` have a `-exec ... +` primary that does essentially the same thing as `xargs`, directly in the `find` command:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/regex_search_term/replace_term/g' {} +
```

This doesn't have all of the options that `xargs` has, so if you need something other than the usual collect-names-and-run-it you should still use `-print0 | xargs -0`.